# why adding sub surface getting this result

Tags: modifiers

i have a simple extrude geometry The mark in red is the sub surface added and without red mark is the original mesh. After adding sub surface to it and im getting odd result. I have remove doubles normals are fix whats the problem. The mesh are united at center. Any solution [image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top and bottom faces of your mesh are single Ngons.
[image]

Change them to quads and the subsurf works as expected.
[image]

Comment: @ OP: after you have filled the first quad, you can select the short edge (between the first and second quad) and consecutively press F

Comment: @3fingeredfrog thanks for replying how to change quads

Comment: "how to change (to) quads" (?)

Comment: Edit mode > Face select mode> select Ngon > Mesh menu > Faces > Triangulate Faces. Then convert those triangles to quads. With the triangles still selected: Mesh menu > Faces > Tris to Quads. Repeat for the other Ngon.